# why automake fails to generate Makefile.in

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

Trying to use automake/autoconf (versions 1.10 and 2.61, respectively).  Everything is working OK, except automake is not generating Makefile.in.

There are some warnings generated, but I don't think they're significant.  However, the last line makes me think it's generating something it shouldn't and stopping there.  There is a md5.cc and md5.c file in the project.

```
xanadu:fsd wwilliam$ automake --add-missing
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
/var/tmp/autoconf/autoconf-15~193/SRC/autoconf/lib/autoconf/specific.m4:421: AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS is expanded from...
/var/tmp/autoconf/autoconf-15~193/SRC/autoconf/lib/autoconf/functions.m4:1677: AC_FUNC_STRNLEN is expanded from...
configure.ac:46: the top level
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_RUN_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_GNU_SOURCE
/var/tmp/autoconf/autoconf-15~193/SRC/autoconf/lib/autoconf/specific.m4:340: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_RUN_IFELSE was called before AC_GNU_SOURCE
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_AIX
/var/tmp/autoconf/autoconf-15~193/SRC/autoconf/lib/autoconf/specific.m4:455: AC_AIX is expanded from...
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_RUN_IFELSE was called before AC_AIX
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_MINIX
/var/tmp/autoconf/autoconf-15~193/SRC/autoconf/lib/autoconf/specific.m4:474: AC_MINIX is expanded from...
configure.ac:46: warning: AC_RUN_IFELSE was called before AC_MINIX
Makefile.am: object `md5.$(OBJEXT)' created by `md5.cc' and `md5.c'
```

Relevant contents of configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT(testapp, 1.1, user@blah.com)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(testapp,1.1)
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

Contents of Makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

CFLAGS=-O2
bin_PROGRAMS = testapp
testapp_SOURCES = interface.cc interface.hh keymgr.cc keymgr.hh main.cc manage.cc manage.hh md5.c md5.cc md5.h mm.cc mm.hh mysqldb.cc mysqldb.h testapp.cc testapp.h
```

I've been googling the issue but haven't found anything helpful.

Commands run were:

```
autoscan
mv configure.scan configure.ac
(edit configure.ac)
autoconf
(edit Makefile.am)
aclocal
automake --add-missing
```

Anyone seen anything like this before or know perhaps how I could turn on some additional debugging to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: OT: You are using an outdated way of calling `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`. The modern usage is: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11])`. If you're using options (and not setting the options in `Makefile.am`, call it like this: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 foreign -Wall -Werror])`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Makefile.am: object `md5.$(OBJEXT)' created by `md5.cc' and `md5.c'
```

is an error message that causes Automake to abort.  These two files would have to be compiled to `md5.o`, so that is a problem.

Can you rename one of these two files?

Comment: Alternative: if they belong to different programs, setting target-specific `CFLAGS` will cause `automake` to generate rules for `foo-md5.$(OBJEXT)` and `bar-m5.$(OBJEXT)`.

Comment: I think this is indeed the answer.  Looking more closely at the program, I don't think the md5.cc file was actually required and could have been removed from the directory.  However, I ended up punting and using CMake as my build system instead.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have one program that I configure with automake.  That program has a script to do the setup, which consists of:

```
aclocal -I config &&
libtoolize --automake &&
autoheader &&
automake --foreign --add-missing &&
autoconf
```

The difference, as I see it, is that in this the `autoconf` step is last, not in the middle.

Comment: The order between `autoconf` and `automake` does not matter, but you should really be calling `libtoolize` before `aclocal`.  You can replace all that script with `autoreconf -vfi` in order to get the correct order.  Just make sure you use `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])` in `configure.ac`, and `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I config` in `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 1):

It complains on line 46, which you do not provide to your question.
Anyhow, to fix this issue you have to add `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` in your `configure.ac`.

example:

```
AC_INIT(testapp, 1.1, user@blah.com)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(testapp,1.1)
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
AC_PROG_C
...
```